# Left-aligning title in org-mode ASCII export?

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

By default, org-mode ASCII export centers the document title (along with the ASCII art lines above and below the title).  What's the best way to center the title in the text output?

Comment: Please do post the same question to emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-ascii-text-width 0))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.